# Cython not recognizing Numpy types

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm learning Cython and can't get a simple example to work.  I have the following code to compute a sigmoid function:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp

cdef inline cnp.float32_t _sigmoid(cnp.float32_t x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))
```

Compiling gives an error `'float32_t' is not a type identifier`

What am I missing?

Comment: the code you posted works on the current versions of cython, so what version are you using ?